# Syncing Evolution without needing gmail?

Tags: email, sync, evolution, calendar

I'm using Ubuntu and want to reduce my Google & Microsoft footprint.

Use Evolution for email, contacts and calendar. Contacts and calendar being synced to laptop and android phone via gmail.

How can I set myself up so that I can sync all three devices directly to Evolution?

I don't have a web hosting account, only email hosting.

Cheers

Comment: You'll need to setup a server with software installed that will provide this kind of services. E-mail account is far from enough.

Answer (score 1):

Since you pay for email (somewhere), you can resolve the email part of this project by setting up [IMAP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-are-imap-and-pop-ca2c5799-49f9-4079-aefe-ddca85d5b1c9) mail clients on laptop & phone following the email host's [IMAP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-are-imap-and-pop-ca2c5799-49f9-4079-aefe-ddca85d5b1c9) configurations, to synchronize email. Don't know what those are, since you didn't specify the name of the email provider, but they will have a help file somewhere which specifies their [IMAP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-are-imap-and-pop-ca2c5799-49f9-4079-aefe-ddca85d5b1c9) requirements. You will have to abandon the Gmail app on your smartphone and replace it with another email client app, so start looking at smartphone mail clients which are [IMAP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-are-imap-and-pop-ca2c5799-49f9-4079-aefe-ddca85d5b1c9) capable, for [there is no Evolution for smartphones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61971/is-evolution-app-available-for-android).

If you don't set up your own server ([helpful hints here](https://syncevolution.org/wiki/http-server-howto)) (and this can be set up in a cloud provider such as Amazon in [AWS](https://www.google.com/search?q=AWS%20for%20dummies) without your having to have a server in your living room scrreching at you 24x7), you will need to pay for a service to sync your calendar and contacts data to your Evolution. There are [third party apps for calendars and contacts on Android](https://alternativeto.net/software/evolution/?platform=android); you need to explore those to see what they require for synchronization with Evolution (this applies if you have your own server for contacts and calendar sharing, too).

This [guide is out of date](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Evolution), but it introduces the basic concepts. This [independent guide](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/caldav/evolution-on-linux/) might help.

If you're not the customer, your privacy (or the lack thereof) is the product; the corollary is you pay for privacy..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. Here's what I did.
My email host handles CalDAV and CardDAV files/databases via Cpanel and they even provided me with set up and direct links to use. No extra charge.

I've now got my calendar and address book created in Evolution synced across 2 computers and my android. The installed app on the Android doesn't like CalDAV so I've dumped that and installed a third part app. It isn't happy about the calendar saying that the host doesn't accept sync-tokens so I will try another App and contact the email host to see if they can help but I am nearing the point where my email, calendar and contacts/address book are now longer exposed to or accessed through a Google product.